# DINOv2 RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Tags: pytorch

I'm new to pytorch and I was trying to make a model using DINOv2, as follows:

```
import argparse
import logging
import os
import random
import sys
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
from pathlib import Path
from torch import optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
from tqdm import tqdm
from data_loading import BasicDataset

import wandb
#from evaluate import evaluate
import evaluate
from functools import partial

dir_img = Path('/home/sort/ved/sort/apple_l2_seg/results/imgs/')
dir_mask = Path('/home/sort/ved/sort/apple_l2_seg/results/masks/')

class ModelWithIntermediateLayers(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feature_model, n_last_blocks, autocast_ctx):
        super().__init__()
        self.feature_model = feature_model
        self.feature_model.eval()
        self.n_last_blocks = n_last_blocks
        self.autocast_ctx = autocast_ctx

    def forward(self, images):
        with torch.inference_mode():
            with self.autocast_ctx():
                features = self.feature_model.get_intermediate_layers(
                    images, self.n_last_blocks, return_class_token=True
                )
        return features

def create_linear_input(x_tokens_list, use_n_blocks, use_avgpool):
    intermediate_output = x_tokens_list[-use_n_blocks:]
    output = torch.cat([class_token for _, class_token in intermediate_output], dim=-1)
    if use_avgpool:
        output = torch.cat(
            (
                output,
                torch.mean(intermediate_output[-1][0], dim=1),  # patch tokens
            ),
            dim=-1,
        )
        output = output.reshape(output.shape[0], -1)
    return output.float()

class LinearClassifier(nn.Module):
    """Linear layer to train on top of frozen features"""

    def __init__(self, in_dim, use_n_blocks, use_avgpool, out_size=1000):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_dim = in_dim
        self.use_n_blocks = use_n_blocks
        self.use_avgpool = use_avgpool
        self.out_size = out_size
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_dim, out_size)
        self.linear.weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=0.01)
        self.linear.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, x_tokens_list):
        output = create_linear_input(x_tokens_list, self.use_n_blocks, self.use_avgpool)
        return self.linear(output)

def setup_linear_classifiers(sample_output, learning_rate, low_res_seg=1024, avgpool=False):
    optim_param_groups = []
    out_dim = create_linear_input(sample_output, use_n_blocks=1, use_avgpool=avgpool).shape[1]
    linear_classifier = LinearClassifier(
        out_dim, use_n_blocks=1, use_avgpool=avgpool, out_size=low_res_seg
    )
    linear_classifier = linear_classifier.cuda()
    optim_param_groups.append({"params": linear_classifier.parameters(), "lr": learning_rate})

    return linear_classifier, optim_param_groups

steps_per_epoch = 1763
def train_model(
        num_classes: int = 5,
        epochs: int = 5,
        dir_checkpoint: str = 'ckpt',
        batch_size: int = 1,
        learning_rate: float = 1e-5,
        val_percent: float = 0.1,
        device: str = "cuda:0",
        save_checkpoint: bool = True,
        img_scale: float = 1.0,
        img_h: int = 224,
        img_w: int = 224,
        amp: bool = False,
        weight_decay: float = 1e-8,
        momentum: float = 0.999,
        gradient_clipping: float = 1.0,
):
    global dir_img, dir_mask
    # 1. Create dataset
    dataset = BasicDataset(dir_img, dir_mask, img_scale)

    # 2. Split into train / validation partitions
    n_val = int(len(dataset) * val_percent)
    n_train = len(dataset) - n_val
    train_set, val_set = random_split(dataset, [n_train, n_val], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(0))

    # 3. Create data loaders
    loader_args = dict(batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=os.cpu_count(), pin_memory=True)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, shuffle=True, **loader_args)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_set, shuffle=False, drop_last=True, **loader_args)

    # 4. Create model
    dinov2_vits14 = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/dinov2', 'dinov2_vits14')
    n_last_blocks = 1
    autocast_ctx = partial(torch.cuda.amp.autocast, enabled=True, dtype=torch.float)
    feature_model = ModelWithIntermediateLayers(dinov2_vits14, n_last_blocks, autocast_ctx).to("cuda")

    pictures = torch.randint(0, 128, (batch_size, 3, img_h, img_w)).type(torch.FloatTensor).to("cuda") # B C H W
    sample_output = feature_model(pictures)

    linear_classifiers, optim_param_groups = setup_linear_classifiers(sample_output, learning_rate)

    # 4. Set up the optimizer, the loss, the learning rate scheduler and the loss scaling for AMP
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(optim_param_groups, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0)
    lossfn=torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

    global_step = 0

    # 5. Begin training
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        with tqdm(total=n_train, desc=f'Epoch {epoch}/{epochs}', unit='img') as pbar:
            for batch in train_loader:
                images, true_masks = batch['image'], batch['mask']

                imagesnorm=(images.cuda()-torch.tensor([0.485, 0.456, 0.406]).view(1,3,1,1).cuda())/torch.tensor([0.229, 0.224, 0.225]).view(1,3,1,1).cuda()
                true_masks = true_masks.to(device=device, dtype=torch.float32)
                true_masks_hot = torch.zeros((images.shape[0], num_classes, img_h, img_w)).to('cuda')
                true_masks_hot = true_masks_hot.scatter_(1, true_masks.to(torch.int64).unsqueeze(1), 1)

                features = feature_model(imagesnorm)
                outputs = linear_classifiers(features)
                out_min = outputs.min(dim=-1)[0].reshape((-1,1))
                out_max = outputs.max(dim=-1)[0].reshape((-1,1))
                outputs = (outputs - out_min) / (out_max - out_min)
                outputs = outputs.reshape((-1, 32, 32)).view((-1, 1, 32,32))
                outputs = F.interpolate(outputs, size=(img_h, img_w), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
                outputs = outputs.squeeze(1)
                outputs = outputs * num_classes
                outputs = outputs.to(torch.int)
                pred_masks_hot = torch.zeros((images.shape[0], num_classes, img_h, img_w)).to('cuda')
                pred_masks_hot = pred_masks_hot.scatter_(1, outputs.to(torch.int64).unsqueeze(1), 1)

                # compute the gradients
                loss=lossfn(pred_masks_hot,true_masks_hot)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()

                pbar.update(images.shape[0])
                global_step += 1

                # Evaluation round
                # division_step = (n_train // (5 * batch_size))
                # if division_step > 0:
                #     if global_step % division_step == 0:
                #         val_score = evaluate(model, val_loader, device, amp)
                #         torch.cuda.synchronize()
                #         print('Validation score: {}'.format(val_score))

        Path(dir_checkpoint).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        state_dict = linear_classifiers.state_dict()
        torch.save(state_dict, str(dir_checkpoint / 'checkpoint_epoch{}.pth'.format(epoch)))
        print(f'Checkpoint {epoch} saved!')

train_model()
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sort/ved/sort/apple_l2_seg/train.py", line 177, in <module>
    train_model()
  File "/home/sort/ved/sort/apple_l2_seg/train.py", line 159, in train_model
    loss.backward()
  File "/home/sort/miniconda3/envs/torch2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 487, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/home/sort/miniconda3/envs/torch2.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 200, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Why I'm getting this error ?